# Is there a way to use CSS to specify colors on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: css, html

I'm collaborating on a checkers program for which the first logical step is to draw the initial board. The implementation we are using has one philosophical issue. The squared are formed by calling `fillRect` with the color of the"dark" squares after initializing the board with the color of the light squares.

My concern is that I now have colors hard coded into the JS, and I would prefer to specify them in the associated CSS. Is there a good way to encode the colors used in drawing the canvas in CSS?

Comment: we need to see some code

Comment: That would mean either parsing the whole CSS files or the computed ones... Dirty js, lots of useless and unrelated scripts. IMO the best in your case is to use a JSON, where you do define a dictionary which will hold your colors.

Comment: Create an element off-screen and give it a color with CSS. Then use getComputedStyle() to read the color of that, and use it to paint your canvas.

Comment: The last comment was actually one of the approaches I had thought of.  Glad to hear it is in the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one or the other, and stick to it. Obviously the game logic would still use JS.

If you want to make it easy to style each part of the board, use CSS and render the parts of the board using actual HTML elements with classes on them. This way you can easily make changes to sizes, colours, images, textures, etc., without explicitly re-rendering anything.

If you want/need it to be on a canvas, you can easily expose a method for setting styling options during or after game creation. This way you can include an inline or second script file as you would with CSS.